# How to translate "to be mean"?

Tags: modal-verbs

Could you help me, I have no ideas what this phrase mean:

> "You must be mean to your classmates"

**EDIT**

I choose a wrong option in the exercise, the phrase should be:

"You **mustn't** be mean to your classmates"

Sorry for my silly mistake :)

Thank you guys, I very appreciate your help!

Comment: Strange. How can anyone advise like this?

Comment: Surely you can't be asking for a translation? You're probably asking what "mean" means. 
In this context (i.e. towards someone) see [wiktionary Etymology 2](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mean#Adjective_2) points 6, 8, 9, 10.

Comment: @MaulikV I was doing an exercise and I had a choice between "must" and "mustn't". Now I see how silly it looks. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"To be mean to someone" equals "to treat someone in an unkind, selfish way".

[*Must* is a modal verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#Must_and_had_to) often used to express logical necessity - that is, not a command but an assumption based on available information.

Hence, the phrase

> "You must be mean to your classmates"

is likely to express the sense of

> It is probable that you treat your classmates in a mean way

Or, more likely, it expands on some preceding statement, drawing a deduction from it:

> I heard you receive no birthday party invitations at all. You must be mean to your classmates.

That is, 'I'm guessing that there is a reason for their coldness towards you, and the probable reason is your meanness towards them'.

Compare:

> I'm told you haven't eaten all day. You must be hungry!

Here's a [page](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/certain-probable-or-possible) explaining this use of the modal verb 'must'.